# How to force script execution before shutdown or reboot is executed? RHEL 7

Tags: linux, systemd, services, shutdown, reboot

I have this service enabled by `systemctl`:

```
[Unit] 
Description=The Oracle Database Service 
After=syslog.target network.target Wants=network.target

[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=65535 
Type=simple 
KillMode=none 
SendSIGKILL=no 
TimeoutSec=5min 
RemainAfterExit=yes 
TimeoutStopSec=5min 
User=oracle 
Group=oinstall 
ExecStart=/home/oracle/acciones/doc/startup.sh
ExecStop=/home/oracle/acciones/doc/shutdown.sh

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target graphical.target
```

The service is working; but after reboot or shutdown the log message indicates that shutdown script was not finished correctly.

Any help appreciated